# How to calculate data offset in a GIF file

Tags: gif

Can anyone explain, how to calculate the data offset?

Here's the example from the website (link below):

```
(1 <<((0xE6 & 0x07) + 1)) * 3 = 384 bytes.
```

E6 equals 230 decimal - but how should I read the rest?

[Example](https://www.file-recovery.com/gif-signature-format.htm)

Comment: Follow the "GIF Format Specification" link at the end of the article: "GCT follows for 256 colors with resolution 3 × 8 bits/primary, the lowest 3 bits represent the bit depth minus 1, the highest true bit means that the GCT is present."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `&` is bitwise AND. `0xE6 & 0x07` is `6`.
2. `<<` is the left-shift operator. `x << y` equivalent to *x× 2<sup>y</sup>*. In this case: `1 << (6 + 1)` is `128`.
3. `*` is the multiplication operator. `3 * 128` is `384`.